# AS3 code xml data fetch

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, scroll

So basicly i have this code for simple text news scroll, but how do i add code for xml data reading(fetch) text for outside source that is wiritten in xml or txt file?
I would also wanted to know how xml file would look like for this code.

```
//SCROLLING SPEED
var scrolling_speed:int = 2;
//TEXT TO SCROLL
var text_to_scroll:String = "This is my text";


//establish the field
var my_text:TextField = new TextField();
//add the field to stage
addChild(my_text);
//set the text
my_text.text = text_to_scroll;
//set the x coord off right side of stage
my_text.x = stage.stageWidth;
//set y coord in middle of stage (about)
my_text.y = (stage.stageHeight/1)-(my_text.height/2.5);
//not selectable
my_text.selectable = false;
//no border
my_text.border = false;
//field scales with more text
my_text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

//set a format
var my_text_format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
//set the color to the hex
my_text_format.color = 0x000000;
//set the font size
my_text_format.size = 28;
//set the font face
my_text_format.font = "Futura Md BT";
//apply formatting
my_text.defaultTextFormat = my_text_format;
my_text.setTextFormat(my_text_format);

//add the listener to scroll
my_text.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,move_text);

//scroll function
function move_text(myevent:Event):void {
    my_text.x-=scrolling_speed;
    if(my_text.x<(0-my_text.width)){
        my_text.x=stage.stageWidth;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your previous questions I saw that you download external XML, for displaying currency exchange rates.

Comment: yes but i would like to have simple xml or txt file with basic info text so i could edit or put in some new info text later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can design your data source (XML) as you wish, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>

    <news>
        <item><![CDATA[Text for news 1]]></item>
        <item><![CDATA[Text for news 2]]></item>
        <item><![CDATA[Text for news 3]]></item>
        <item><![CDATA[Text for news 4]]></item>
        <item><![CDATA[Text for news 5]]></item>
        <item><![CDATA[Text for news 6]]></item>
    </news>
</data>
```

Before working with data, don't forget to preload it:

```
var xmlLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var myData: XML;
var myItems: XMLList;
var position: uint;
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("path/to/xml"));

function onComplete(e : Event): void{
    myData = new XML(URLLoader(e.currentTarget).data);
    myItems = myData..item;
}
```

Change texts in the textfield from the data source:

```
function move_text(myevent:Event):void {
    my_text.x-=scrolling_speed;
    if(my_text.x<-my_text.width){
        my_text.x=stage.stageWidth;
        //Set next text
        if(++position >= myItems.length()){
            position = 0;
        }
        my_text.text = myItems[position];
    }
}
```

And don't forget to initiate text field with first element from the XML